# jquery $.post doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery-ui, postback

Why doesn't post work? 
This works ok:

```
function validateEmail($element) {
    var val = $.trim($element.val());
    if (!isRequired(val)) {
        module.showError($element,
                                 translate_error_required.replace("%s", 
                                      $element.closest("div.fblock")
                                              .find("div.label label")
                                              .text()
                                              .replace("*", "")))
    }
    else {
        if (!isValidEmailAddress(val)) {
            module.showError($element, translate_error_email)
        }
        else {
            if (!checkUserName) {
                module.showError($element, translate_error_usedemail)
            }
            else {
                module.showCompleted($element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this doesn't work, may be since post doesn't work because variable `user_name` doesn't get passed to `checkuser.php`.

```
function checkUserName(checkuser){
        var user_name = $("#add-email").val();
                    alert(user_name);
        $.post("checkuser.php", {user_name: checkuser} , function(data){            
            if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null){                  
                data=='true';
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

this `checkuser.php` code works ok but I don't know why it doesn't get `user_name`

```
<?php include('../connect.php');
      $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']); 
      $query  = mysql_query("select Email from members limit 1");           

      $numrow=mysql_fetch_array($query); 
      if($numrow['Email']== $username){
           echo 'false'; 
           exit;
      }else{
            echo 'true';
      }
 ?>
```

this code work

Comment: can u show the HTML you working on?

Answer (score 0):

`if(!checkUserName)` is not a function call, and you are not passing it your variable. Instead you should be:

```
if(!checkUserName(val)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I forget it, but after adding val the post variable don't pass and